# Display Information in a Right Column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Goal:
Make the name of the component to be on the left side (first colum) and the right side (second column)you should have different object like input textbox etc in relation to browser's solution 981px .The result is located in this link "`https://jsfiddle.net/2w9kskr2/`".

Problem:
When I add the solution that is "@@media screen and (min-width: 981px) {" (`https://jsfiddle.net/jdvdpwwj/`) the result is not the same as the goals description (`https://jsfiddle.net/2w9kskr2/`).

Info:
I'm using bootstrap v2

```css
    .div-table{
      display:table;         
      width:auto;         

      border-spacing:5px;/*cellspacing:poor IE support for  this*/
    }
    .div-table-row{
      display:table-row;
      width:auto;
      clear:both;
    }
    .div-table-col{
      float:left;/*fix for  buggy browsers*/
      display:table-column;         
      width:150px;         
    }

    .div-table-col2{
      float:left;/*fix for  buggy browsers*/
      display:table-column;         
      width:415px;         
    }


    #A, #Text, #From, #T {
            width: 421px;         
    }
```

```html
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  

        
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  



<div class="div-table">

  <div class="div-table-row">
    <div class="div-table-col">
      <label for="A">A</label>
    </div>
    <div class="div-table-col2">
      <input id="A" name="A" placeholder="A" value="" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="div-table-row">
    <div class="div-table-col">
      <label for="T">T</label>
    </div>
    <div class="div-table-col2">
      <input id="T" name="T" placeholder="T" value="" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="divRow">
    <div class="div-table-col">
      From
          <br/>

    </div>
    <div class="div-table-col2">
      
      
    <button id="From" style="margin-bottom:10px;" title="122344" data-id="From" type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle form-control selectpicker btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="filter-option pull-left">122344</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span></button>
      
      <br/>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="divRow">
    <div class="div-table-col">DD & DD</div>
    <div class="div-table-col2">
      
      
      <select id="SSS" style="max-width: 200px;"></select>
      
      
      <select id="SSS" style="max-width: 200px;"></select>
   
      
      
    </div>
    
    
    
    
    
    

    
    
    
  </div>  

  
  
    <div class="div-table-col">
      <label for="AWB">Message </label>    
    </div>
    <div class="div-table-col2">  
      <textarea name="Text" id="Text" cols="10" rows="10" class="input-large">
      </textarea>
    </div>    
    
    

  
  
  </div>
```

Comment: [Fix](https://jsfiddle.net/jdvdpwwj/1/) @@media to be just @media

Comment: That is true, I'm using ASP.net as a backend and that is why I'm using @@ insted of @

Answer (score 0):

You get the answer here it think https://jsfiddle.net/thwnvo29/

```
.div-table-row{
      display:block;
      width:100%;
      float:left;
    }
    .div-table-col{
      float:left;
      display:block;      
      width:20%;         
    }
    .div-table-col2{
      float:left;
      display:block;         
      width:80%;         
    }
    .div-table-col2 input,.div-table-col2 button,.div-table-col2 textarea {
      width:100% !important;
    }
```